# Cloudwatch alarm action failed to execute scale down policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling, cloudwatch-alarms

I have added auto scale up and down policy with terraform. While scale up works fine, scale down fails to execute without any error message.

```
Failed to execute action <scale-down-policy-arn>. Received error: ""
```

There was suggestion to make sure that single alarm triggers the policy, that I have make sure.
Cloudwatch alarm is on `ALARM` state.

I'm using insufficient data as `BREACHING`